# How to save Core Data to use later?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata

Right now on my iPhone application I'm saving a **large chunk of data** from a `NSData` object to `NSUserDefaults`. I know that's not the best approach because `NSUserDefaults` is meant only to store small pieces of data.

I'm doing this something like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData alloc]init]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"MyData"];
```

For late retrieval of this data.

What's the correct way to save this `data` permanently for further use?

Comment: Create an archive-able object, I'll post an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom class with the properties you want (.h file):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomHolder : NSObject {
    NData *data;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *data;

@end
```

And then set the .m file up so that you can encode/decode the object

```
#import "CustomHolder.h"

@implementation CustomHolder

@synthesize data;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
    [encoder encodeObject:data forKey:@"data"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder 
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        self.data = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"data"]; 
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then you can just `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:obj toFile:[self saveFilePath]]` to save and `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self saveFilePath]]` to load.

This works for any kind of data, and gives you the option of adding as many different data files as you need to an object.

Comment: Then again, he could just NSData writeToFile:/initWithContentsOfFile:

Comment: True, I just use the custom class method because it allows me to put more data variables in the same location later and because some writeToFile methods are deprecated (although not NSData's).

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults are handy for small amounts of data, not complex data structures
There is no real 'permanent' way of saving data unless you have an external server that stores it, but Core Data is a good way of storing is on the device as long as the application doesn't get deleted.

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) by Ray Wenderlich is a good starting point. Takes you through NSManagedObject concepts, fetchRequests etc.
There's several parts to it so you can incrementally build your data schema

Good luck